# How can I make the player flip when it touches ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gravity thing and when they touch the ceiling I want the player to flip, my code doesn't work and I wonder if there is a better way to do this. I'd also like to know how to make the player not rotate to those exact coordinates and just where the player is already facing.

```
IEnumerator GravitySwitch()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 10.0f, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        if (grounded)
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 180);

    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -10.0f, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        if (grounded)
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply the scale of your player's scale vector by:

```
new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

can try

```
transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 180.0f, Space.Self);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html