# How can I make the player flip when it touches ground or ceilng

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gravity thing and when they touch the ceiling I want the player to flip, my code doesn't work and I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Here's the code I currently have.

```
IEnumerator GravitySwitch()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 10.0f, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -10.0f, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that "flips" your character. All I see is code that switches gravity.

Comment: Anti-gravity code! (maybe that is why it is malformed :)

Comment: @MrMoonMan i left it out sorry, but do you know if theres code that would work for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make the player flip when it touches ground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835022/how-can-i-make-the-player-flip-when-it-touches-ground)

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the size of the player object by -1. Try using that.